# Getting value of input array in jquery and passing it to PHP

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have multiple input fields like this:

```
<input type="text" name="childage[3]" placeholder="0"/>
<input type="text" name="childage[8]" placeholder="0"/>
<input type="text" name="childage[12]" placeholder="0"/>
```

I want to get them into jQuery and pass them with AJAX to php but remember the keys (3, 8, 12). Is this possible?

I tried until now the following:

```
$('input[name="childage[]"]');
$('input[name="childage"');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at the `serialize` method:

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize

You'll want to grab all the form elements, something like this:

```
<input class="age-box" type="text" name="childage[3]" placeholder="0"/>
<input class="age-box" type="text" name="childage[8]" placeholder="0"/>
<input class="age-box" type="text" name="childage[12]" placeholder="0"/>

var ages = $('.age-box').serialize();
$.post(url, ages, function(data) { //handle response from the server });
```

Comment: Note that serialize will replace `[` and `]` for url encoding. You will have to replace them back `$('.age-box').serialize().replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']');` or with something similar.

Comment: Thank You! In php i used parse_str($_POST['fields'], $fields); and it works

Answer (score 0):

You could use hidden input fields and set the values to the numbers you need:

```
<input type="hidden" value=3 />
<input type="hidden" value=8 />
<input type="hidden" value=12 />

// Get the values
$('input[type="hidden"]')[0].val();
$('input[type="hidden"]')[1].val();
$('input[type="hidden"]')[2].val();
```